# PHP create page as a string after PHP runs

Tags: php, function

I'm stuck on how to write the test.php page result (after php has run) to a string:

testFunctions.php:

```
<?php

function htmlify($html, $format){
    if ($format == "print"){


        $html = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $html);
        $html = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $html);
        $html = str_replace("&nbsp;", "&amp;nbsp;", $html);
        $html = nl2br($html);
        return $html;
  }
};

$input = <<<HTML
<div style="background color:#959595; width:400px;">
&nbsp;<br>
input <b>text</b>
<br>&nbsp;
</div>
HTML;

function content($input, $mode){
  if ($mode =="display"){
    return $input;
  }
  else if ($mode =="source"){
    return htmlify($input, "print");
  }; 

};

function pagePrint($page){

  $a = array(
    'file_get_contents' => array($page),
    'htmlify' => array($page, "print")
  );  
  foreach($a as $func=>$args){
      $x = call_user_func_array($func, $args);
      $page .= $x;
  }    
  return $page;
};


$file = "test.php";
?>
```

test.php:

```
<?php include "testFunctions.php"; ?>


<br><hr>here is the rendered html:<hr>

<?php $a = content($input, "display"); echo $a; ?>

<br><hr>here is the source code:<hr>

<?php $a = content($input, "source"); echo $a; ?>


<br><hr>here is the source code of the entire page after the php has been executed:<hr>
<div style="margin-left:40px; background-color:#ebebeb;">
<?php $a = pagePrint($file); echo $a; ?>
</div>
```

I'd like to keep all the php in the testFunctions.php file, so I can place simple function calls into templates for html emails.

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/ob_start?

Comment: [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [output buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php) to capture the output of an included file and assign it to variable:

```
function pagePrint($page, array $args){
 extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
 ob_start();
 include $page;
 $html = ob_get_clean();
 return $html;
}

pagePrint("test.php", array("myvar" => "some value");
```

And with `test.php`

```
<h1><?php echo $myvar; ?></h1>
```

Would output:

```
<h1>some value</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, couldn't get this one to work, got a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\_Localhost\_Tools\testFunctions.php on line 41

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for but it seems you want to build an engine of sorts for processing email templates into which you can put php functions?  You might check out http://phpsavant.com/ which is a simple template engine that will let you put in php functions directly into a template file as well as basic variable assignment.

I'm not sure what printPage is supposed to be doing but I would re-write it like this just to make it more obvious because the array of function calls is a bit complicated and I think this is all that is really happening:

```
function pagePrint($page) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($page);
    return $page . htmlify($contents,'print');
};
```

and you might consider getting rid of htmlify() function and use either of the built-in functions htmlentities() or htmlspecialchars()

Comment: Thanks for the reply. this solution returns a bunch of php. I need the php converted first. in the original pagePrint I was trying to use call_user_func_array as from my understanting (as limited as it is) it could offer a similar result to ob_start to parse the php before printing it (which I also couldn't get to work btw)

Comment: ah cool, yea i didn't think the function above would do what you wanted either, but I thought it would have been a simplified version of that that function actually was doing...  yeesh, hard to explain that in a few words!  If you are making a template engine, though, savant already does that and you can have it return the results as a string rather than echo to the browser.

Comment: Thanks. I've had a look at savant and smarty, but would rather make something simple myself. I think another issue with this is that it loops on itself. I've since moved the printPage function over to the testFunctions.php so that it is not reading itself. However I'm still having difficulty parsing php before assigning it to a string, even after playing around with ob_start() as suggested below.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like my original method may not have been the best way of going about it. Instead of posing a new question on the same topic, figured it was better to offer an alternate method and see if it leads to the solution I am after.

testFunctions.php:

```
$content1 = "WHOA!";
$content2 = "HEY!";
$file = "test.html";

$o = file_get_contents('test.html');

$o = ".$o.";

echo $o;

?>
```

text.php:

```
<hr>this should say "WHOA!":<hr>

$content1

<br><hr>this should say "HEY!":<hr>

$content2
```

I'm basically trying to get $o to return a string of the test.php file, but I want the php variables to be parsed. as if it was read like this:

```
$o = "
    <html>$content1</html>
";
```

or

```
$o = <<<HTML
<html>$content1</html>
HTML;
```

Thanks!